# How to start function in js file A while it is declared in js file B and avoid errors by wrong order?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 js files registered in the header in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MyCompanyName/js/Libraries/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MyCompanyName/js/Libraries/jquery.scrolldepth.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MyCompanyName/js/custom.js?v=1.3"></script>
```

In "jquery.scrolldepth.min.js" there is a function named "scrollDepth()". This function is using jQuery. In the custom.js I would like to start the function "scrollDepth()" which is declared in the js file "jquery.scrolldepth.min.js". I would like also to start this function after "jquery-1.9.1.min.js" and "jquery.scrolldepth.min.js" is loaded. Is this ok in my custom.js? I would like to avoid errors that the needed js files are not loaded.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery.scrollDepth();
    });
});
```

The script above comes from [here](http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/).

UPDATE!

Sometimes I see this error in the IE developer bar:

**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollDepth' 
custom.js, line 599 character 9**

Here is the source from the page where I got the error in the developer bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="nl" dir="ltr">
    <head>            
<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', 'UA-64013448-1', 'auto');ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');ga('send', 'pageview');</script>

        <link href="/_layouts/15/MyCompany/Js/Libraries/jqueryui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MyCompany/js/Libraries/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MyCompany/Js/Libraries/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MyCompany/js/Libraries/jquery.scrolldepth.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MyCompany/js/nl.MyCompany.js?v=1.3"></script>
</head>
```

And [here](https://raw.github.com/robflaherty/jquery-scrolldepth/master/jquery.scrolldepth.min.js) is the jQuery script.

Comment: Have you tried it? Is there an error?

Comment: yes I tried it. See update for the error I see.

Comment: Could you show this in context, script in the html file?

Comment: see update for the html source.

Comment: just include the relevant script headers, and your jquery code